# Parse Query Wrapping Error, works fine on simulator crashes on device

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

The code below runs fine on the simulator then crashes on two devices and works on one device.

I'm also getting this:

```
function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded> of Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ()).(closure #2)
```

Would it possibly have to do with bridging obj-C into my swift application?
Any suggestions

```
var query = PFUser.query()
query?.whereKey("username", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
var users = query?.findObjects()

//Loop through users
if let users = users as? [PFUser]{
    for user in users {
        //println(user.username)
        self.userArray.append(user.username!)
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel?.text = userArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to perform the query in the background so the UI (main thread) stays responsive. Try the following:

```
if let currentUsername = PFUser.currentUser()?.username {
    var query = PFUser.query()!
    query.whereKey("username", notEqualTo: currentUsername)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            if let users = objects as? [PFUser] {
                for user in users {
                    self.userArray.append(user.username!)
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("query error: \(error) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The following line:
if let currentUsername = PFUser.currentUser()?.username?

? must be followed by a call, member lookup or subscript

Comment: Delete the ? after username and it works. I'll correct the previous post

Comment: I have deleted the ? after username, however the users don't load

Comment: Try adding some println() statements to figure out where it's gone awry. When using Parse, the username field is not automatically set unless you use facebook/twitter login.

Comment: I added println(user.username)
and its printing:
Optional("foo")
Optional("test")

Comment: Are you printing this inside the for loop? Do you have two users whose usernames are "foo" and "test"? I can't give any meaningful response without some context

Comment: Sorry yes all of my users are appearing as Optionals and they are being printed inside the for loop

Comment: Your prior comment was very deceiving. You said that the users don't load, but they are being loaded from the query. The issue lies with how you are handling the query response. The username attribute of PFUser is an optional variable. Since you are just printing it as is, that's why it's showing up as Optional("foo"). If you force-unwrap it by using println(user.username!) then the optional will go away. On a related note, the safer way to do it would be to use an if-let statement like before

Comment: The Optional still displays by force unwrap in 
println(user.username!)
I have an array outside of this function to append the users to a tableview
hence,  self.userArray.append(user.username!)

Comment: if let username = user.username { self.userArray.append(username) }

Comment: I've tried this still doesn't display, I've edited my post to show how I've configured the reuse identifier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88631/discussion-between-russell-and-daisy-r).

Answer (score 0):

The first place I'd look is the forced unwrap of the optionals. Every one of those is asking for a crash -- when `PFUser.currentUser()` returns nil and user.username returns nil:

Try:

```
   var query = PFUser.query()
   if let query = query, 
   currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() as? PFUser, 
   currentUsername = currentUser.username {
      query.whereKey("username", notEqualTo: currentUsername)
      var users = query.findObjects()

      //Loop through users
      if let users = users as? [PFUser]{
           for user in users {
               //println(user.username)
              if let username = user.username {
                   self.userArray.append(username)
              }
          }
      }
```

Comment: There is a downcast issue for PFUser